# GJK algorithm in case of circle and polygon

Tags: algorithm, collision

I wonder if it's possible to modify GJK so I can use it to detect collision between circle and n points polygon. 
I implemented for polygon and polygon before, and I tried modifying the support function (to get furthest point of a circle), but apparently, this results in infinite loop. 
Is this possible to do? do I need to change other thing than the support function? (because I don't see any) 
 
Here's what I use to get furthest point in a circle btw

```
maxPointCircle = new Vector2(circle.center).add(new Vector2(direction).mul(circle.radius));
```

Answer (score 0):

GJK algorithm actually tells you the minimal distance between two polygons (and when the distance is 0 it's a collision).
So for a polygon and a circle, you can use GJK to find the minimal distance between that polygon, and the center point of the circle, then compare that distance with the radius of the circle. If the distance is less than or equal to the radius, then it's a collision.

The algorithm looks like:

```
collision(polygon1, circle):
  polygon2 = dummy polygon of only one point, which is the center of the circle
  distance = GJK(polygon1, polygon2)
  if distance <= circle.radius:
    return true
  else:
    return false
```